# Next.js: Module not found: Can't resolve 'canvg'

Tags: javascript, material-ui, next.js

I have a `next.js` project and I keep getting:

```
error - ./node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.es.min.js:458:25
Module not found: Can't resolve 'canvg'
```

I'm not sure why because I'm not including either `jspdf` or `canvg`.

Not sure what's causing it. Any help would be appreciated. I'm using `material-ui` if that matters.

Comment: If you do `npm ls jspdf` that should help you determine what has it as a dependency.

Comment: @shamoon could you share your `package.config` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems dependency error means that particular Module is missing when it's running.

Run `npm ls or yarn list` will print to stdout all the versions of packages that are installed, as well as their dependencies, in a tree-structure. Then search for that particulate packages are listed or not.
Run `npm ls jspdf or yarn list jspdf` then you can see its list of dependencies in tree-structure.

Please check your `node` version is updated or not ? If not then update first.

Quick & Dirty way: delete `package.lock or yarn.lock` file and delete `.node_modules` folders And Then run `npm install or yarn` to install again.
Look at console while you installing and make sure there are no error in the installing process. If you saw error you better look that massages also.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using `react-pdf`, which supposedly has `canvg` as an optional dependency (it or one of its dependencies) even though it was apparently required during a `yarn build`.

At first, I installed my dependencies using `yarn install --frozen-lockfile --ignore-optional` in a pipeline and I got that error.

I simply removed the `--ignore-optional` flag and now my install script is working.